# Windows server user for scanning to folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, security, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I want to create a user whose only purpose is for network photocopiers to be able to scan to a specific folder (let's say, `E:\Data\scan`, shared as `\\server\scan`, to which other users will have rw access). The scanner user wouldn't be able to do anything other than scanning to that specific folder.

I could just create a regular domain or computer user and set permissions accordingly, but I'd like to know what the best practices are. For all intents and purposes, all I'm looking for is a credential for the photocopiers to be able to write to that share; all the other stuff users are able to do, the user profile, etc, are of no interest.

I'd like to know if I should add the user to any of the many groups available.

I'd like to know if there is a way to disable that user's access to anything except the scan folder, i.e. the user wouldn't be able to even run programs or see any other part of the filesystem, nor log physically onto the server (something similar to the 'guest' account on desktop Windows would do as well).

This is a very small office network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could create a regular domain or computer user and set permissions
>   accordingly, but there's so many options when creating a user on
>   Windows Server that I'd like to know what the best practice is.

I don't know what options you're referring to, but this isn't really a complex undertaking.

Create a user account. Grant the user account the appropriate Share and NTFS permissions to the shared scans folder. Configure your scanner to use this user account.

It really isn't any more complicated than that. This is how everyone does it.

Comment: I've edited the question; but if everyone does it that way, I suppose it's good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it that way would mean this scanner user may logon anywhere. If someone figured out its password, that is. So as enhancement, I suggest you should allow this account only to logon to your scan target machine - that is how we use it.